# Associate data tables and automatically update them in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basically, I've got 3 data tables. "jobs", "periods", and an associated table "JobPeriodAssociation".

Now, the JobPeriodAssociation displays every possible combination of jobs and periods. E.g. i've got 2 jobs (j1, j2) and 2 periods (t1, t2), the table will display 4 rows: j1t1, j1t2, j2t1, j2t2.

If I now add a period in the "periods" table, it automatically updates the "JobPeriodAssociation" table by adding a (blank) 3rd period/job combination. I.a. j1t1, j1t2, j1t3, j2t1, j2t2, j2t3.

This is accomplished by a change action in the periods_controller

```
def change
@mynumber_of_periods = params[:mynewnumber].to_i
@number_of_periods = Period.count
number_of_missing_periods=@mynumber_of_periods - @number_of_periods

if number_of_missing_periods > 0
  @jobs = Job.all
  @nanns = Nann.all
  (1..number_of_missing_periods).each do |number|
    name="t#{number+@number_of_periods}"
    @new_period=Period.create!(name: name)
    @jobs.each { |jo|
      JobPeriodAssociation.create(job_id: jo.id, period_id: @new_period.id, demand: 1, wtp: 0, minage: 0, maxage: 0, genderjf: 0, genderjm: 0, genderji: 0, minval: 0, children: 0, dlj: 0, faj: 0, pcj: 0)
    }
    @nanns.each { |na|
      NannPeriodAssociation.create(nann_id: na.id, period_id: @new_period.id, available: 1, wage: 0, age: 0, value: 0, genderf: 0, genderm: 0, childrenn: 0, dl: 0, fa: 0, pc: 0)
      Matching.create(nann_id: na.id, period_id: @new_period.id)
    }
  end
end
```

(+obviously some minor alterations in routes and the index views)

I did the same for Jobs, meaning that changing the amount of jobs results in automatic alterations in the JobPeriodAssociation.

```
  def change
@mynumber_of_jobs = params[:mynewnumber].to_i
@number_of_jobs = Job.count
number_of_missing_jobs=@mynumber_of_jobs - @number_of_jobs

if number_of_missing_jobs > 0
  @periods = Period.all
  (1..number_of_missing_jobs).each do |number|
    name="j#{number+@number_of_jobs}"
    @new_job=Job.create!(name: name)
    @periods.each { |per|
      JobPeriodAssociation.create(period_id: per.id, job_id: @new_job.id, demand: 1, wtp: 0, minage: 0, maxage: 0, genderjf: 0, genderjm: 0, genderji: 0, minval: 0, children: 0, dlj: 0, faj: 0, pcj: 0)
    }
  end
end

if number_of_missing_jobs < 0
  (@mynumber_of_jobs +1 ..@number_of_jobs).each do |number|
    name="j#{number}"
    Job.find_by_name(name).destroy
  end
end
```

Now the problem is this: I've also got an option to simply create a new job.

```
  def new
@job = Job.new
  end
```

The corresponding form to create a new job looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@job) do |f| %>
<% if @job.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@job.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this job from     being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @job.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
 </div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :name %><br>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :demand %><br>
<%= f.number_field :demand %>
</div>

.
.
.

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :pcj %><br>
<%= f.number_field :pcj %>
</div>


<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

If I create a new job and not just "change" the amount of jobs, I want this change to also apply to the JobPeriodAssociation table but and can't seem to find a way.

Very thankful for any suggestions!

Comment: I would recommend moving all the logic inside the change methods of the controllers into the corresponding models, and then using the after_create callback to call the methods

Comment: Could you explain more what you want to do? What do you mean by "not just change the amount of jobs?

Comment: @Jeremie in the first listing you can see that changing the amount of jobs results in the creation of a new job with predefined params (in this case demand: 1 and the rest 0). However, if I choose to create a NEW job, i can enter all these params manually. This would result e.g. in a job with params (demand: 3, and the rest some other numbers). And this newly created job is supposed to be updated in the JobPeriodAssociation table as well.

Comment: So, if I understand well, if you create a new job (j4), you want to have associations created for existing period, like j4t1, j4t2, ...

Comment: @Jeremie exactly ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this to the method creating the job :

```
def create
  @job = Job.new(params[:job])
  if @job.save
    periods = Period.all
    periods.each do |period|
      @job.periods << period
    end
    # Do the usual rails redirect
  end
end
```

For this to work, your models should have the correct associations defined.

Comment: Hey Jeremie, thank you!!! Please check out my other Answer (since I wanted to include an image I had to post an answer instead of a comment ;) )

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Jeremie thank you so much! This did the trick for me. Anyway, now I'm afraid automatically adding the job to the JobPeriodAssociation leaves me with blank traits. When creating a job, I create it with several params (see the image attached here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGTmg.png). As of now, the params don't get pushed to the JobPeriodAssociation table and I only figured out a way how to hard code them as can be seen in the first listing of this topic

```
@new_job=Job.create!(name: name)
@periods.each { |per|
  JobPeriodAssociation.create(period_id: per.id, job_id: @new_job.id, demand: 1, wtp: 0, minage: 0, maxage: 0, genderjf: 0, genderjm: 0, genderji: 0, minval: 0, children: 0, dlj: 0, faj: 0, pcj: 0)
}
```

However, I would like to push the created jobs including its params to the JobPeriodAssociation as displayed in the image attached. Do you have any thoughts on that?

again, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Maybe the best would be to open a new question for this as it is different from the scope of the current question.